# Escape special characters in Apache pig data

Tags: apache-pig

I am using Apache Pig to process some data.
My data set has some strings that contain special characters i.e `(#,{}[])`.

This [programming pig book](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/load_and_store_funcs.html) says that you can't escape those characters.

**So how can I process my data without deleting the special characters?**

I thought about replacing them but would like to avoid that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading your data?  There is no way to escape these characters *when they are part of the values in a tuple, bag, or map*, but there is no problem whatsoever in loading these characters in when part of a string.  Just specify that field as type `chararray`.

The only issue you will have to watch out for here is if your strings ever contain the character that Pig is using as field delimiter - for example, if you are `USING PigStorage(',')` and your strings contain commas.  But as long as you are not telling Pig to parse your field as a map, `#`, `[`, and `]` will be handled just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be,

```
input = LOAD 'inputLocation' USING TextLoader() as unparsedString:chararray;
```

TextLoader just reads each line of input into a String regardless of what's inside that string. You could then use your own parsing logic.

Answer (score 0):

When writing your loader function, instead of returning tuples with e.g. maps as a String (and thus later relying on [Utf8StorageConverter](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/Utf8StorageConverter.html) to get the conversion to a map right):

```
Tuple tuple = tupleFactory.newTuple( 1 );
tuple.set(0, new DataByteArray("[age#22, name#joel]"));
```

you can create and set directly a Java map:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
map.put("age", 22);
map.put("name", "joel");
tuple.set(0, map);
```

This is useful especially if you have to do the parsing during loading anyway.