# Unable to Remove Special Characters In Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a text file that I want to Load onto my Pig Engine, 
The text file have names in it in separate rows, and the data but has errors in it.....special characters....Something like this:

```
Ja@@$s000on   
J@@a%^ke
T!!ina
Mel@ani
```

I want to remove the special characters from all the names using REGEX ....One way i found to do the job in pig and finally have the output as...

```
Jason
Jake
Tina
Melani
```

Can someone please tell me the regex that will do this job in Pig.
Also write the command that will do it as I unable to use the **REGEX_EXTRACT** and **REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL** function.
Also can someone explain what is the Significance of the number 1 that we pass to this function as Argument after defining the Regex.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use REPLACE with RegEx to solve this problem.

```
input.txt  
Ja@@$s000on  
J@@a%^ke T!!ina Mel@ani  

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' as line;  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'([^a-zA-Z\\s]+)','');  
dump B;  

Output:  
(Jason)  
(Jake Tina Melani)
```

Comment: Yes this function did work out.
One more thing, when do u need to use the FLATTEN Operator.
Because every load operators stores data in a bag right...so can i use such fucntions like REPLACE directly on the data or i need to flatten the file first?

Comment: If you use REPLACE operator then FLATTEN is not required. If you use REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL, then FLATTEN is required, bcoz by default REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL return Tuple as a output datatype.

Answer (score 0):

`There is no way to escape these characters when they are part of the values in a tuple, bag, or map, but there is no problem whatsoever in loading these characters in when part of a string. Just specify that field as type chararray`

Please Have  a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806221/escape-special-characters-in-apache-pig-data)